# Vue: Mysterious ghost props?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

In my project, I came across the following code:

#### Parent component - `<ParameterModal>`:

```html
<template>
  <modal-wrapper props="...">
    <!-- ... other templates similar to this... -->
    <template v-else-if="modalTemplate === 'bitmask_set'">
      <template slot="header">
        <h4 class="center-text">{{title}}</h4>
      </template>
      <div v-if="errorMessage" class="error-message">
        {{errorMessage}}
      </div>
      <ModalBitmaskSet
        v-bind="modalMeta"
        :setErrorMessage="setErrorMessage"
        :clearErrorMessage="clearErrorMessage"
      />
    </template>
    <!-- ... -->
    <div v-else>
      Warning: unmapped modal template!
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
  </modal-wrapper>
</template>
```

Ok, cool, this is using a regular slot and named slot to display a component called `<ModalBitmaskSet>`. So I look inside `modal-wrapper` to find the outlets...

#### Child component - `<modal-wrapper>`

```html
<template>
  <!-- some container and wrapper elements and then... -->
  <div class="modal-header">
    <slot name="header" />
  </div>
  <div
    :class="['modal-body', 'display-flex', 'flex-direction-column', modalTemplate]"
  >
    <div
      id="escape_message"
      style="text-align: center; display: none; padding-bottom: 10px;"
    >
      You have unsaved changes.<br />Please click Save or Cancel to proceed.
    </div>
    <md-content v-if="modalContent">{{modalContent}}</md-content>
    <slot />
  </div>
  <!-- end containers and wrappers -->
</template>
```

Also cool, there is where the slots are coming out... but how are props being passed to `<ModalBitmaskSet>`? When I look in Vue DevTools, I can see that props are somehow being passed to this component that don't exist in the parent. On top of this, when I add new components to `<ParameterModal>`, they sometimes don't get passed props that other components seem to be getting! This is very weird!

[image: vue devtools showing mysterious ghost props being passed into component]

As you can see from the photo, this component is somehow getting passed props that aren't listed in the code! Specifically, the props `colIndex`, `fieldSet`, `indexOffset`, `methodIndex` and `rowIndex` in this case, although other components on this `<ParameterModal>` component appear to get different props.

Am I missing something? Where could these ghostly props be coming from?

Comment: Maybe default values for props?

Answer (score 0):

This line seems the likely cause, though without seeing the code for `modalMeta` it's difficult to be sure:

```
v-bind="modalMeta"
```

This is using the object `v-bind` syntax, so whatever properties exist in the `modalMeta` object will be passed as props to the component.

See:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind